# Реализовать на MS SQL. Вычисление завязанное на количество итераций

Tags: sql, sql-server, циклы

Имеется таблица с данными по датам.

```
   if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#tmpTable') is not null 
drop table #tmpTable

create table #tmpTable
(
    id      int identity    not null,
    value1  int                 null,
    value2  int             not null,
    Dtm     date            not null,
    Result  int                 null
)


insert into #tmpTable 
(
    value1,
    value2,
    Dtm
)
values 
    (110, 10, '20180401'),
    (null, 12, '20180402'),
    (null, 45, '20180403'),
    (null, 70, '20180404'),
    (null, 10, '20180405')
```

Необходимо из первого значения value1 вычесть следующее по дате  значение поля value2. Номер операции (1) записать в Result. Полученное значение записать в поле value1 той же строки, где находится value2. Затем взять получившееся значение value1 и вычесть из него след. по дате значение поля value2.Номер операции (2) записать в Result. И так до конца.

Имеется код, написанный на python с такой логикой, но там циклами идёт перебор. Как перегнать в SQL - не знаю.  Исползовал и оконки и пытался применить рекурсию на ОТВ. Не получается. Заминка происходит именно в тех задачах, где необходимо получить номер операции и записать его и в вычитании след. значения value2 из получившегося value1. Подскажите, как это можно реализовать.

Comment: Если версия сервера позволяет - используйте обычный запрос на изменение (UPDATE) с применением оконных функций LAG() и ROW_NUMBER().

Comment: @Akina, нет, сервер не позволяет использовать оконные функции при update.

Comment: *сервер не позволяет использовать оконные функции при update* А это тут при чём? Вообще - умеет? ну стройте (в секции WITH) подзапрос на выборку данных, который получит нужные данные, а в другой копии исходной таблицы выполняйте обновление.

Comment: @Akina, проблема как раз и заключается, что я не могу вычислять со значением, кот. я должен записать в value1 после первого прохода. Это значение я получаю в отв with, но использовать не могу

Answer (score 1):

С использованием `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ...)` и `SUM(...) OVER (ORDER BY ...)` как-то так:

```
WITH
tmp1 AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        rowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Dtm)
    FROM #tmpTable
),
tmp2 AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        newValue = SUM(IIF(rowNum = 1, value1, -value2)) OVER (ORDER BY Dtm)
    FROM tmp1
)
UPDATE tmp2
SET
    Result = rowNum,
    value1 = IIF(rowNum = 1, value1, newValue);
```

Функции `LAG` и `LEAD` не пригодились.

Результат (`SELECT * FROM #tmpTable`):

```
id  value1  value2  Dtm        Result
--- ------- ------- ---------- -------
1   110     10      2018-04-01 1
2   98      12      2018-04-02 2
3   53      45      2018-04-03 3
4   -17     70      2018-04-04 4
5   -27     10      2018-04-05 5
```